# React Native + Typescript: how to dinamically render a Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've been struggling for 3 hours with this problem.

```
  const steps = [
    {
      Component: ChooseGameMode,
      props: {
        initialValue: gameMode,
        onComplete: handleChooseGameModeComplete
      }
    },
    {
      Component: ChooseGameType,
      props: {
        initialValue: gameType,
        onComplete: handleChooseGameTypeComplete
      }
    },
    {
      Component: ChooseGameSeverity,
      props: {
        initialValue: gameSeverity,
        onComplete: handleChooseGameSeverityComplete
      }
    },
    {
      Component: ChooseGamePlayers,
      props: {
        previousPlayers: previousPlayers,
        initialValue: gamePlayers,
        onComplete: handleChooseGamePlayersComplete
      }
    }
  ];

  const {Component: CurrentComponent, props: currentComponentProps} =
    steps[currentSetupStepIndex];
```

Given the following code I'd need to render the component `CurrentComponent` with the relative properties `currentComponentProps` but I can't figure out the right way because typescript is slapping (deserved) me in the face.

I've would have done something like `<CurrentComponent {...currentComponentProps} />` but it is obviously too easy to be true.

Thank you for the help.

**UPDATE**

Here's my current solution, but I'm not convinced enough.

```
  //////////
  // Render
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {React.createElement(
        CurrentComponent as React.ComponentType<typeof currentComponentProps>,
        currentComponentProps
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
```

The compiler is seeing this:

```
const currentComponentProps: {
    initialValue: GameMode | null;
    onComplete: (mode: GameMode) => void;
    previousPlayers?: undefined;
} | {
    initialValue: GameType | null;
    onComplete: (type: GameType) => void;
    previousPlayers?: undefined;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

If someone has a better one it would be really appreciated for educational purpose, not for my case.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I think just `as const` on the array should work there

Comment: The @Willow 's post helped me a lot although i didn't use exactly the same solution. Here's mine ```React.createElement(
        CurrentComponent as React.ComponentType<typeof currentComponentProps>,
        currentComponentProps
      )``` and the compiler is not barking anymore

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this pattern would be better served by skipping JSX?

You should be able to use React.createElement instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

```
return React.createElement(
  CurrentComponent,
  currentComponentProps,
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've written a comment as post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584496/3204718

Comment: After reading your response, I realize that Typescript is also going to typecheck the interface of CurrentComponent and currentComponentProps - to see if they are compatible.   The underlying issue is that the type of `steps` where you define all these things creates a union of all the possible types, but not all the possible types are compatible.  I agree that the linked duplicate at the top is the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it gives:

```
const CurrentComponent: React.MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameModeProps) => JSX.Element> | React.MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameTypeProps) => JSX.Element> | React.MemoExoticComponent<...> | React.MemoExoticComponent<...>
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameModeProps) => Element> | MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameTypeProps) => Element> | MemoExoticComponent<...> | MemoExoticComponent<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<{ initialValue: GameMode | null; onComplete: (mode: GameMode) => void; previousPlayers?: undefined; }> | ComponentClass<{ ...; }, any>'.
      Type 'MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameTypeProps) => Element>' is not assignable to type 'string | FunctionComponent<{ initialValue: GameMode | null; onComplete: (mode: GameMode) => void; previousPlayers?: undefined; }> | ComponentClass<{ ...; }, any>'.
        Type 'MemoExoticComponent<({ initialValue, onComplete }: ChooseGameTypeProps) => Element>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{ initialValue: GameMode | null; onComplete: (mode: GameMode) => void; previousPlayers?: undefined; }>'.
          Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
            Type 'PropsWithChildren<{ initialValue: GameMode | null; onComplete: (mode: GameMode) => void; previousPlayers?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'ChooseGameTypeProps'.
              Types of property 'initialValue' are incompatible.
                Type 'GameMode | null' is not assignable to type 'GameType | null'.
                  Type 'GameMode.SINGLE' is not assignable to type 'GameType | null'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: This should be a comment on @Todd 's post